# Good Practice handle InterruptedException in JEE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, future, interrupted-exception

I have a JEE application that uses a TimerService to run every 3 mins.

Each run the computation can last maximum 1min30s. To cap it to a max time I am using Future API like this :

```
 ----------------------------------------------
 // EJB TimerService
 ----------------------------------------------
 private void computeThread() {
    final Future<?> future = this.executor.submit(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            compute();
        }
    });

    try {
        future.get(this.maxDelay, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (@SuppressWarnings("unused") final InterruptedException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Job Interrupted.");
    } catch (final ExecutionException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Execution Exception : " + e);
    } catch (@SuppressWarnings("unused") final TimeoutException e) {
        future.cancel(true);
        LOGGER.warn("Compute interrupted by TimeOut.");
    }
}

@Timeout
public void timerTimeout(final Timer timer) {
    // simplified
    computeThread();
}

----------------------------------------------
//EJB Computation (Singleton)
----------------------------------------------

@EJB
private transient DataWsEJB dataEJB;

@EJB
private transient EngineEJB engineEJB;

@EJB
private transient EJBA ejbA;

@EJB
private transient EJBB ejbB;

public void compute() {
    // some computations and calls on EJBs
}
```

The compute() function calls the calculation in another EJB (a Singleton).
This Singleton has multiple EJBs (stateless most of the time) injected.

My trouble is that when the InterruptedException is risen from anywhere in EJBs (ejbA or ejbB for example), the exception is caught first time but then I have anothers that are not. 
What would be the good practice to catch it ? 
Should I add throws on every method that can be called during this computation ? (I find this too much) or Should I catch it a level under but I have some warnings from Eclipse that methods used does not throw InterruptedException.

I found a lot of answers on Java SE projects but none on JEE projects.

Comment: Please add the entire class's code!

Comment: An `EJB` would not throw any `InterruptedException`s...

Comment: added some code ...